# C# retrieving an object associated with thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to C# and only have a rudimentary understanding of threading so sorry if I'm asking the question based on incorrect assumptions.

I have a method that looks this:

```
public async Task<ServiceResult> AttemptConnectionAsync()
        {
            return new ServiceResult(true);
        }
```

I am calling this method from a different class:

```
Task<ServiceResult> sr = someObjectInstance.AttemptConnectionAsync();
```

How do I get the ServiceResult, the object itself "attached" to the thread and access its attributes instead of the thread? Like this:

```
Assert.IsNull(ServiceResult.Errors);
```

Comment: Since you're getting started with async (and your question has already been answered), I recommend reading [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) article and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article by Stephen Cleary. Misusing async can result in a deadlock within your application, depending on where and how you're using it. Reading these should help you avoid trouble in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `await` keyword like this:

```
ServiceResult sr = await someObjectInstance.AttemptConnectionAsync();
```

To learn more about Asynchronous Programming you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/async).